Searching the movie with huge brain like a cube
Searching the movie where "Big Daddy who's watching you" was a big (huge) funny and sad brain like a cube - natural AI. Maybe you know this movie?

Some facts I remember:

secret agency invites psychotherapist/psychologist to help their AI
the brain ia a huge funny and sad brain
psychologist is a woman (i'm not sure)
brain can feel feelings, emotions
film in color
released after 2000. Maybe after 2010 (not sure)
time period was it showing: today or near future


Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

here should be tag "neural networks"

When was it released? - I don't remember. I'm sure after 2000. Maybe after 2010!

This sounds exactly like the episode 'Bob' from the show Dimension 404. Dimension 404 is a show on Hulu similar to Black Mirror on Netflix, but with a much more tongue-in-cheek feel to the show.
The episode 'Bob' is about a female military psychologist who is taken by the FBI to counsel their terrorist monitoring system. It just so happens that their monitoring system is a giant biological cube shaped brain named 'Bob'. Bob is hitting a mental block trying to track down a specific terrorist and it's the psychologist's job to get him to work though the block.


Why hire a mere human to do our racial profiling when we can grow a giant cube-shaped brain in a vat?!  We have the technology, people!
